# An inscribable trapezoid has lateral sides $3$ and $5$, and its mid-line divides its area in the ratio $5:11$. Find the bases.

Tags: geometry

The lateral sides of trapezoid are equal $3$ cm and $5$ cm. We can draw circle in this trapezoid. The mid-line divides trapezoid into $2$ parts, where their area's ratio is $5:11$. Find the bases of the trapezoid.

Comment: Can you show us work so far?

Comment: only the drawing so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Take trapezoid ABCD with $AB||CD$

Since the trapezoid is convex, in order for a circle to be inscribable in the trapezoid we must have $AB+CD=AD+BC$

The midline divides the trapezoid into two areas in the ratio of $5:11$. Call the areas $1$ and $2$

Now take the shorter base as $x$ and longer base as $y$ then the midline will be $\dfrac{x+y}{2}$.

Now consider the height $h$.......

Can you continue from here?

Comment: yes, thank you very much!